# biblatex's iffieldundef always returns true on origdate

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to customized biblatex's  authoryear.bbx file to include the original publication date. My simple strategy is to:

1. define a printorigdate command
2. wrap that command into a \iffieldundef command and insert it into the author macro of  my customized authoryear.bbx

However, I always get a negative result from iffieldundef, even when the origdate field is present.

Here is a simple example, with a debugging string added for clarity:

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MvBook{Hegel1970a,
  author           = {Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich},
  title            = {Werke [in zwanzig Bänden]},
  editor           = {Eva Moldenhauer and Karl Markus Michel},
  langid           = {german},
  publisher        = {Suhrkamp},
  volumes          = {20},
  abstract         = {Auf der Grundlage der Werke von 1832-1845 neu edierte Ausgabe},
  address          = {Frankfurt am Main},
  shortitle        = {TWA},
  year             = {1986},
  origdate         = {1969/1971}
}

@Book{Hegel1971a,
  author           = {Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich},
  title            = {Frühe Schriften},
  shortitle        = {TW1},
  year             = {1986},
  langid           = {german},
  volume           = {1},
  modificationdate = {2024-02-20T17:30:50},
  crossref         = {Hegel1970a},
  }
}


\end{filecontents}

% \usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-ibid-movie,citestyle=authoryear-icomp, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,citestyle=authoryear-icomp, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}\space\printfield[parens]{nameaddon} %line added to include the name addon
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%% ADDED LINES
  \iffieldundef{origdate}%
  {\mkbibbrackets{NO ORIG DATE}}
  {\printorigdate}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%
  }
  
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
  \end{document}
```

I am expecting to see [NO ORIG DATE] after the first ref's date, and [1969-1971] for the second one. Instead, here is what I get:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Does  \iffieldundef perform a different test?

Comment: date fields are split up by biber, so you must test e.g. against origyear, see 4.2.4.3 Date Component Fields in the documentation. And be aware that crossref entries inherit fields.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I must have missed the splitting part. Sometimes biblatex's manual gets a bit too terse...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

biblatex/biber postprocess a date and split it up in various components. This is described in the documentation in section 4.2.4.3 Date Component Fields. So if you look into the generated .bbl from your example you can see that there is no `origdate` field. The entries (both of them as the second inherits the field through the crossref!) contains the following fields related to `origdate`:

```
      \field{origendyear}{1971}
      \field{origyear}{1969}
...
      \field{origenddateera}{ce}
      \field{origdateera}{ce}
```

So you need to test for example for `origyear` and with this your output looks like this:

[image]